# Simple & Cheap dance floor instead of carpet

Tags: floor, plywood

I'm having a large group over for a party. Since my living room is carpeted, I'm trying to think of clever ways to create a nicer dance floor than the carpet. One thought was two 8x4 pieces of plywood with the smooth side up to make an 8x8 foot floor. The problem then is how to join them along the 8' seem?

Any other ideas are also appreciated. Although the google results are for making more complicated traditional dance floors. I'm not trying to go all out. I'm just exploring options for something quick and easy that's better than carpet.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Depending on the pile of the carpet, sheets of plywood laid on top may create an unstable surface (especially at the edges).

Comment: You may be able to find a local vender that rents dance floors. I have no idea what pricing would be like, but it might be something to look into.

Comment: I'm not trying to promote the idea to use plywood but I would think good solid stuff that was 3/4" thick would lie nicely on most carpet surfaces. The biggest issue with the plywood is the abrupt edge. Parquet rental floors come with a very nice tapered edge that so there is not that "drop off" surprise.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that if you got nice looking hardwood covered plywood at 3/4" the cost of two sheets will be more than the cost of renting the wood parquet indoor dance floor. The rental company in my community quotes a price that is quite reasonable for a 9'x9' dance floor. See http://www.thepartypros.com/equipment.asp?action=category&category=13&key=DanceFloorWoodPa

Comment: First, thank you all for your comments and answers! You definitely helped me.

Ecnerwal is right, 8x8 is too small. We have invited 60 people of that ~25 confirmed so I'm planning on ~35 people. I measured part of the room that would be ideal for this and I could fit a 12x16 floor. That's 192 sqft so 5 sqft for each person which is more than enough as less than half will probably even use it anyways.

Floor rental doesn't seem with it for this type of get together. The cheapest floor rental at places nearby is $195. The cheapest lowes laminate is $0.78/sqft so that's $150.

Comment: In my upstairs gym, I have 2 8x4 3/4" plywood sheets laying next to each other on carpet. Then another 2 sheets on top laying in the opposite direction. On top of that are stall mats. This is stable enough for barbell lifts so it's stable enough for dancing I think. The problem with that is stall mats are high friction so not good for dancing :) Home depot does have plywood sheets with very smooth sides that are a little more $ but not bad at all so I thought I could lay them together but then what do I do about seams. Also like Michael said, what to do about the drop off at the edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple approach (and the one I'd suggest above any of the following) is to have a sock-hop (take off your shoes and dance on the carpet) and the most workable approach to a one-time need for a hard floor is to rent a dance floor (they are a standard rental-store item, as seen at weddings done in huge tents, etc...) 8x8 is a rather tiny dance floor for "a large group" and raw plywood in your living room is not going to enhance the decor (rental floors are usually parquet or faux-parquet)

If for some reason you want to buy something you'll need to store, these days laminate flooring (that interlocks at the seams) might be both more practical and cheaper than trying to get plywood to stay flat. It will also store more compactly. If you opt for large sheet goods, tempered hardboard (Masonite®) will be a better bet than plywood (it's far more prone to stay flat) and can be joined with a heavy tape. 1/4" will work better than 1/8"

Comment: I don't think laminate flooring would work well over carpet,  at least not without a rigid  substrate.

Comment: This is the best idea except that laminate is not as cheap as plywood. I priced the cheapest laminate at $0.78/sqft but I bet I could find cheaper. Masonite is a good idea although not as cheap per thickness as plywood. Right now 2 layers of 3/4" plywood is stable on the carpet. Do you think I'd need the same thickness of Masonite?